# When classifying triangles as obtuse, acute, or right by checking $c^2>a^2+b^2$, $c^2<a^2+b^2$, or $c^2=a^2+b^2$, why must $c$ be the longest side?

Tags: geometry

I'm currently studying [I.M. Gelfand Trigonometry Book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0149-6) and looked at *Appendix I, Classifying Triangles.* In this section, it looks at classifying triangles to either obtuse, acute, or right using the converse of the Pythagorean Theorem ($c^2>a^2+b^2$, $c^2<a^2+b^2$, $c^2=a^2+b^2$). I have a few questions regarding this, along with an example provided in the book.

**Question 1:** For each of the equations in the converse, whether it be $c^2>a^2+b^2$, $c^2<a^2+b^2$, or $c^2=a^2+b^2$, why does $c$ *always* have to be the longest side length of the three in a triangle? For example, a triangle with side lengths $5, 3, 7$ is  obtuse since $7^2=49>3^2+5^2=9+25=34$, considering that $c$ is the longest length ($7$). If I were to set $c$ as $5$, $5^2=25<3^2+7^2=9+49=58$, the result would be tell otherwise, saying that the triangle is acute. So why can't I set $c$ as one of the shorter lengths?

**Question 2:** In the book, Gelfand provided an example:

In a (non-official) [solution book](https://philip-healy.github.io/gelfand-trigonometry-solutions/gelfand-trigonometry-solutions.html), the author wrote that the answer to the question was simply that "The obtuse angle will always be opposite the longest side." How does his sentence answer the question?

Comment: A triangle is obtuse iff the largest angle is obtuse. The largest angle "*will always be opposite the longest side*", so it's enough to check that one. You already know that the two smaller angles are always acute.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, a comparison between $c^2$ and $a^2+b^2$ can always be made no matter the ordering of the side lengths. If $c^2<a^2+b^2$, then the angle opposite side $c$ is always acute; if $c^2=a^2+b^2$, then the angle opposite side $c$ is always right; if $c^2>a^2+b^2$, then the angle opposite side $c$ is always obtuse.

However, if you want to classify the *whole triangle* as acute, right, or obtuse, then you need to classify specifically the *largest* angle. To target that angle we recognize it as being opposite the longest side.

Answer (score 1):

> *For example, a triangle with side lengths $5, 3, 7$ is  obtuse since $7^2$ $=49$ $>3^2+5^2$ $=9+25$ $=34$, considering that $c$ is the longest length ($7$). If I were to set $c$ as $5$, $5^2$ $=25$ $<3^2+7^2$ $=9+49$ $=58$, the result would be tell otherwise*, ***saying that the triangle is acute***.

I believe the bolded part is where your confusion lies. $\,5^2 \lt 3^2 + 7^2\,$ does *not* say that the *triangle* is acute. All it says is that the *angle* opposite the side of length $\,5\,$ is acute.

It is not wrong to check all three inequalities, and if you find one with $\,\gt\,$ then conclude that the triangle is obtuse. But it is redundant and unnecessary, since there can be at most one obtuse angle in a triangle, and that can only be the largest angle, which is "*opposite the longest side*". So it is enough to check the inequality for the longest side, in this case $\,7\,$.

Same goes for checking whether a triangle is a right triangle. It is enough to check Pythagoras' equality for the longest side, since there can be at most one right angle in a triangle, and that can only be the largest angle, opposite the longest side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why $c$ has to be the longest side in a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$. However, if you are assigning letters to the sides of a triangle and it doesn't matter which letters are used, often $c$ is assigned to the longest side. This has happened so often that people have come to expect it.

As well, the set of three conditions you gave depend on using $c$ as the longest side. In a formal work this requirement would be specified; I expect it would be specified in your textbook, though I don't know the book. It would make little sense to have nine conditions, with three to apply when $a$ is longest, three others for when $b$ is longest and the last three for when $c$ is longest. The reader is expected to be able to translate between different label systems when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a general triangle $\triangle ABC$ with side lengths
$a = \lvert BC\rvert$, $b = \lvert AC\rvert$, and $c = \lvert AB\rvert$,
without any assumption that $c$ is the longest side.
Note that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive numbers.

Then by the law of cosines,

$$  c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos( \angle ACB). $$

Solving for $\cos( \angle ACB)$, we get

$$ \cos( \angle ACB) = \frac{a^2 + b^2 - c^2}{2ab}. $$

Since $2ab$ is positive, $\cos( \angle ACB)$ and $a^2 + b^2 - c^2$ have the same sign.
So we have one of the following three cases:

\begin{align}
c^2 < a^2 + b^2 &\iff a^2 + b^2 - c^2 > 0 \iff \cos(\angle ACB) > 0 \iff
\text{$\angle ACB$ is acute.} \\
c^2 = a^2 + b^2 &\iff a^2 + b^2 - c^2 = 0 \iff \cos(\angle ACB) = 0 \iff
\text{$\angle ACB$ is a right angle.} \\
c^2 > a^2 + b^2 &\iff a^2 + b^2 - c^2 < 0 \iff \cos(\angle ACB) < 0 \iff
\text{$\angle ACB$ is obtuse.} 
\end{align}

So if you just want to know the acute/right/obtuse status of one angle in a triangle, certainly you can label the opposite side $c$ and proceed to compare $c^2$ with $a^2 + b^2$ without regard to whether the side you labeled $c$ is the longest side.

But if you want to know whether a **triangle** is acute, right, or obtuse,
you cannot just look at one angle at random to decide.
In order to detect a right triangle you must find the right angle in that triangle,
and in order to detect an obtuse triangle you must find the obtuse angle in that triangle.

Now suppose you labeled the triangle so that $a$, not $c$, is the longest side.
That is, $c < a$.
Then $a^2 + b^2 > a^2 > c^2$, so we can be sure that the angle $\angle ACB$
opposite side $c$ is acute.

That means $\angle ACB$ is one of the acute angles of an acute triangle, or one of the two acute angles of a right triangle, or one of the two acute angles of an obtuse triangle. But which kind of triangle is the triangle? It could be any of the three kinds. You have learned nothing about the acute/right/obtuse status of the triangle.

You have a similar lack of information about the triangle in the case where $c < b$.

The only way to find a right angle in a triangle, knowing only the lengths of the sides, is to discover a labeling of the side lengths $a$, $b$, $c$ so that
$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.
This can only happen if the sides are labeled so that $c > a$ and $c > b$.

Similarly, in order to find an obtuse angle, we need to label the sides so that
$c^2 > a^2 + b^2$, which can only happen if $c > a$ and $c > b$.

So you let $c$ be the longest side because that's the only way to find a right angle or obtuse angle in the triangle if there is one.
If you let $c$ be a shorter side you'll only find one of the acute angles that all triangles have.

Comment: @Blue Well, don't I feel foolish! But it's corrected now, I think.